# How can I instead adbd tool in my device?

Tags: android, adb, android-source

The adb tool has a tow module, the one is `adb` on the PC and the another is the `adbd` on device.

Now I added some log lines into the adb source code, then I compiled the adb source code and generate a new adbd file in:

target Symbolic: adbd (out/target/product/msm8625/symbols/sbin/adbd)

But I can't find the `/sbin` folder and the `adbd` file on my device. Is there anybody who uses their own `adbd`?  How can I use mine instead of the original?

Comment: You need to root your phone to access `sbin` folder

Answer (score 2):

The adbd binary resides in the /sbin directory of the ramdisk from a decompiled boot.img.

To use your own adbd binary you would:

1. Decompile your boot.img

   - There are specific utilities to do this:

     - mkbootimg, unpack-bootimg.pl & repack-bootimg.pl
   - Or you could something more user friendly like [Dsixda's Android Kitchen](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246).
2. Replace the default adbd binary in the /sbin directory of the ramdisk with your modified one.
3. Recompile the boot.img
4. Enjoy!

If you are making modifications in the adbd binary to enable root access in adb shell, you may also want to make modifications to the default.prop file; more specifically changing these entires -

```
ro.secure=1
ro.allow.mock.location=0
ro.debuggable=0
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp
ro.adb.secure=1
```

to something like this:

```
ro.secure=0
ro.allow.mock.location=0
ro.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
ro.adb.secure=0
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Android-Image-Kitchen (AIK) to decompile/comlipe boot.img
https://github.com/osm0sis/Android-Image-Kitchen

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-android-image-kitchen-unpack-repack-kernel-ramdisk-win-android-linux-mac.2073775/

adbd binary in any android device is located in boot.img

```
\ramdisk\sbin\adbd
```

so you can delete previous ver. and paste your own adbd binary here

```
\ramdisk\sbin\
```